# What is the difference in meaning between the "baptizand/baptisand", "baptized/baptised", and "baptizee"?

Tags: difference, etymology

#### Actual, recent usage

I encountered a new term recently, referring to a person to be (or has been) baptized: the ["*baptizand*"](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/baptizand).  The context is this 2022 video [Rebutting Gavin Ortlund on Baptismal Regeneration](https://www.catholic.com/audio/cot/rebutting-gavin-ortlund-on-baptismal-regeneration) (minutes 16:38-17:12) where Gavin Ortlund used the term twice in the same paragraph:

> Two of the specific points of emphasis in the Baptist tradition for what God is doing through baptism because it’s not just us show our faith or something, God is at work in it. One is the emphasis upon the gathered community, it’s not just for the **[baptizand]**, it’s for everyone who is gathered. And it’s giving a visible portrait of the Gospel to everyone who is present, and God is communicating grace to those who observe in faith. And so the language of sign and seal that you find throughout the reform tradition, that isn’t just with reference to the **[baptizand]**.

although the transcriber (I think) makes a mistake in rendering it "baptizeined" in the transcript, maybe owing to the rarity of this word in common usage, **although** I'm pretty sure Gavin got it from recent scholarly books on baptism referenced by *Wiktionary*.  The way Gavin pronounced it validates that he really meant "baptizand" and that he **meant** it as a technical term since he also used "baptized" a lot, although never "baptizee".

Later on, Gavin used it once more:

> It’s really interesting, the whole set of catechetical lectures opens with this warning about Simon the Magician in Acts 8 who’s baptized, and he doesn’t have faith. And it says that basically his baptism does nothing for him. And he’s offering all these warning throughout of basically don’t be a Simon. And he says if you don’t repent, the water will receive you but the spirit will not accept you. And he says this throughout. In lecture three section four, he says, “Neither does he that is baptized with water but not found worthy of the spirit receive the grace and perfection.” Now, this is not going to be a problem for all views of baptismal regeneration but to the extent that you get infant baptism and then a disconnect between the regenerative work of baptism and saving faith in the **[baptizand]**. These passages are going to require some kind of explanation.

#### My question

Short of simply emailing Gavin himself, I wonder whether there is a difference in meaning between "the baptizand" and "the baptized"?  It is clear that "*baptized*" means a person *already* baptized.  Maybe "*baptizand*" refers to a *candidate* for baptism?  Or maybe it is simply to refer to one of the party *in the scene* of the baptism ceremony?

There is also the word ["*baptizee*"](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/baptizee).  How is it different than "*baptizand*"?  Can I substitute "baptizee" for "baptized"?  Or can "baptizee" only be used *prior to* baptism?  Can we thus infer that "baptizee" is different from "baptizand" in that the former doesn't have the "candidate" connotation?  Or is "baptizee" interchangeable with "baptizand" as a word pointing to one of the parties in the ceremony?

Is there an etymological connection between the three, or regional variations in which the three terms are used?

Comment: [The *-and* suffix to mean "the object of a verb" is pretty rare in English.](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Category:English_terms_suffixed_with_-and)  I'd never heard of *baptizand* before; I can think of *operand* and *multiplicand*, but that's about it.

Comment: It's a new one on me, but an _ordinand_ is a candidate for ordination. I suspect that _baptizand_ refers to the candidate _at the time of the ceremony_.

Comment: It's interesting that 3 of us came up with 4 different examples of the form - none of them common.  My favourite [regex dictionary](https://www.visca.com/regexdict/) returns 131 nouns ending *-and*.  "Analysand" is a clear addition, but "ligand" in chemistry appears to be [formed the same way](https://www.etymonline.com/word/ligand). "Baptisand" and "graduand" don't make that list

Comment: @ChrisH Interesting to see the etymology of *ligand* - I never made the connection between *ligand* and *ligature* before, but there it is: *ligand* is basically "that which is tied"!

Comment: @stangdon it only occurred to me as I skimmed the list (I'm a physicist who's worked on some physical chemistry projects).  "Aha" I thought, "I bet *ligand*" works the same way

Comment: For what it's worth, the suffix of _operand_, _multiplicand_, and _baptizand_ is essentially the same as the suffixes of _dividend_ (literally "that which is to be divided"), _propaganda_ (literally "that which is to be propagated"), and _agenda_ (literally "those which are to be done"), as well as the name _Amanda_ (literally "she who is to be loved").

Comment: Good point @TannerSwett - those  slightly different forms (different conjugations and genders in the Latin from which the English terms come) give us much more common examples

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You link to Wiktionary, which doesn't support your "(or has been)" with examples. All of the examples are clear that the baptisand is in the process of being baptised, or at least it's imminent.  Once they've been baptised, "baptised" is a more appropriate term.

You might compare "[graduand](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/graduand)" (wiktionary again) - one who is about to graduate.  In my experience it's only used for students  in the context of their degree ceremony.  Until shortly before the ceremony they're a student, by the end of the ceremony they're a graduate.

The common feature of the etymology of these and the examples in the comments, is the Latin [gerundive](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gerundive), in the first conjugation, with the *-us* ending dropped in English.  The Wikipedia article on the gerundive has some related formations (including the female names Amanda and Miranda) and further reading.

Comment: I should have clicked on the triangle to read the quotations.  I recognize the authors of the 4 quotations, all eminent and recent Christian scholars, so those samples are good ones to cull for dictionary purposes.

Comment: Sorry, I added "baptizee" into the mix.  It would be great if you could update your answer.

Comment: I'll point you to ["employee"](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/employee), absentee, apraisee (one who is employed, absent, or being appraised), etc. for comparison. The [*-ee*](https://www.etymonline.com/word/-ee) suffix is more common than *-and*, coming from the French past participle ending *-é*.  With *baptizee* appearing in few dictionaries (and most of them identical), I can only speculate that it would refer to someone during the process, like *baptisand*.

Comment: _-ee_ is a more productive suffix in current English than _-and_ for "a person having something done to or for them". _-and_ tends to get used only in technical contexts (technical in this case being to do with the Christian hierarchy and administration). So it is not at all surprising that somebody would invent the word "baptizee" for a person about to be baptised. The iWeb corpus has two instances of _baptizee_ and one each of _baptisee_, _baptizand_ and _baptisand_.

Comment: @ColinFine I agree.  I couldn't find enough on *bapti[zs]ee* to add it to my answer.

Comment: @ColinFine Actually, your comment that *-and* is for "a person having something done to them" is a more precise meaning if the term is used *during the process*, since the priest would literally dunk the person in water or sprinkle water to the person while saying "I baptize you in the name of the Father, the Son, and the Holy Spirit".

Answer (score 2):

None of these are very common.

Adult baptism is relatively unusual (in my culture) so the person to be baptized would normally be called "the baby". No special word is needed.

If one needed a more specific term, I'd probably use "the candidate for baptism", and this is supported by [this ELU answer](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/368805/what-do-you-call-someone-being-baptised-christened).  "The candidate" would be clear, in context.

"Baptizand" is the kind of word that might be made up on the spot on the model of "graduand", and mean a person who has recently been baptised, or sometimes, the person who is to be baptised (there is some variation between Christians on whether baptism is symbolic or sacramental, for some the ceremony with the water is merely a celebration of joining the faith, rather than something magical).  It's not a word that has any significant currency.

In theory the recently baptized is just "A Christian". Again, no special word is needed.

In 50 years I doubt I've ever seen or used such a word. Attempts to analyse the etymology seem pointless, since there isn't sufficient evidence of use over history.

Comment: Yes, I have never heard it before myself, but based on usage in recent scholarly literature as well as recent oral usage (2022) by a credo-baptist theologian / Baptist pastor who knows what he is talking about (see my edit in the Q), if I were a lexicographer I *have* to include it in my dictionary, hence relevance to this SE.

Comment: That might make it better for [English.se] more than here